# RabbitMQ Camel Consumer - Consume a single message

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a scenario where I want to "pull" messages of a RabbitMQ queue/topic and process them one at a time.
Specifically if there are already messages sitting on the queue when the consumer starts up.
I have tried the following with no success (meaning, each of these options reads the queue until it is either empty or until another thread closes the context).

1.Stopping route immediately it is first processed

```
final CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
try {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            RouteDefinition route = from("rabbitmq:harley?queue=IN&declare=false&autoDelete=false&hostname=localhost&portNumber=5672");
            route.process(new Processor() {
                Thread stopThread;

                @Override
                public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    String name = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY, String.class);
                    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

                    // Doo some stuff
                    
                    routeComplete[0] = true;
                    if (stopThread == null) {
                        stopThread = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                        public void run() {
                                try {
                                    ((DefaultCamelContext)exchange.getContext()).stopRoute("RabbitRoute");
                                } catch (Exception e) {}
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    stopThread.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    context.start();
    while(!routeComplete[0].booleanValue())
        Thread.sleep(100);

    context.stop();
}
```

2. Similar to 1 but using a latch rather than a while loop and sleep.
3. Using a PollingConsumer

   ```
    final CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.start();
    Endpoint re = context.getEndpoint(srcRoute);
    re.start();
    try {
        PollingConsumer consumer = re.createPollingConsumer();
        consumer.start();
        Exchange exchange = consumer.receive();
        String bb = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        consumer.stop();
    } catch(Exception e){
        String mm = e.getMessage();
    }
   ```
4. Using a ConsumerTemplate() - code similar to above.

I have also tried enabling preFetch and setting the max number of exchanges to 1.

None of these appear to work, if there are 3 messages on the queue, all are read before I am able to stop the route.
If I were to use the standard RabbitMQ Java API I would use a basicGet() call which lets me read a single message, but for other reasons I would prefer to use a Camel consumer.

Has anyone successfully been able to process a single message on a queue that holds multiple messages using a Camel RabbitMQ Consumer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the primary intention of the component as its for continued received. But I have created a ticket to look into supporting a basicGet (single receive). There is a new spring based rabbitmq component coming in 3.8 onwards so its going to be implemeneted there (first): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16048

Comment: Thanks very much Claus, I appreciate this is an edge case but am glad there will be an option in the future.